# How to load information in an open Excel from a PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have this code and what it does is that it keeps information inside an excel, in this case "Hello World!" , but what happens is that the excel has to be closed so that said execution can be performed and when I try to do it with the open excl it sends me an error. Could you load information with an open excel?

this is the error that comes out

```
 Warning: unlink(prueba/consulta.xlsx): Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\importexcel\lib\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php on line 214

 Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Renaming temporary file failed: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\importexcel\lib\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php on line 347

 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file prueba/consulta.xlsx.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\importexcel\lib\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php:348 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\importexcel\f.php(24): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('prueba/consulta...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\importexcel\lib\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php on line 348
```

and this is the code that I present

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'lib/PHPExcel/');

require_once 'lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require_once 'lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
$fileType = "Excel2007";
$fileName = "prueba/consulta.xlsx";

// Read the file
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

// Change the file
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A4', 'HELLO')
        ->setCellValue('B4', 'WORD!');

// Write the file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
$objWriter->save($fileName);

?>
```

Comment: I think we need to go back a few steps. Why do you have the data in an Excel sheet? Why do you need to keep it open? What is in the Excel sheet that you need in the PHP program? It sounds like a xy problem to me

Comment: to see, what happens is that I'm going to extract information from a database that I have in mysql, I will pass it to php and with the code that I publish I could upload it to excel, since in excel they have a platform already done and what I'm looking for values, so since this excel platform is in constant use, what I'm looking for is that every time I upload information to excel I do not have to close it, and it can be open for when the information comes up

Comment: Of course you can't save changes to an open file. People shouldn't be running Excel on the same server that is running PHP. And the library you're using has been deprecated for years. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/README.md

Comment: Of course, in a computer we will use the php and in another computer I will use the excel ... so there would be no problem when loading information in a computer (php) and show it in an open excel in another computer? ... in my case just try to do both on my own computer.
I realize my code with PHPEexcel, but it can be done with the PhpSpreadsheet? I will have some reference that you can give me